# What could be the reason for my laptops to burn down all the time

Tags: laptop, gpu

First time it happened when my laptop (ACER Predator with GTX 980M) suddenly turned off. I wasn't able to start him and the power adapter was dead. On repair service they told me that the problem was burnt chip on the motherboard, and that the adapter is good, only the fuse was the problem.

Three months after that service, he started to blue screen just a few seconds after the start-up. I noticed that he is not discovering dedicated GPU, and every process that tries to use her just causes blue screen. This time I sent him to repair service, they said that chip on the GPU is fried and that they need to replace her. I had to wait for parts, so I bought a second laptop (ASUS TUF with RTX 3050ti).

One month after using this laptop, the same thing happened. No GPU detected, but this time he wasn't popping blue screen all the time, I just couldn't use my dedicated GPU.

After I sent second laptop to repair service, the first one came back, with story that he doesn't want to accept new GPU chip, and that they can reset it, but then my whole laptop could've become useless (not sure what all that means). I wanted to disable that GPU later, and use only integrated, but after an hour, the screen went black, and nothing was happening. I could hear ventilators, and indicator LEDs were up, but nothing on screen.

The only common thing to both of them was the main power source and second display I was using with them. I used the same mouse and headphones, but I guess that they couldn't make those problems. The thing with power is that every time i plug in something, the sparks go out. But my roommates are also using a lot of computers, laptops, phones and monitors to, and nothing ever happened to any of our other devices, only my laptops had problems.

Second possible thing is that monitor i was using. It is a very old LCD monitor with cheep adapter from VGA to HDMI.

So I was wondering what could be the reason for my problems.

And what should I do with that first laptop, is it worth trying another repair service?

Comment: I am guessing that "reset" in "to accept new GPU chip, and that they can reset it," was 'reseat' (think desolder, and resolder it for BGA chips).

Comment: That could be the thing. Should I send him to other repair service?

Comment: Some laptops are just poorly designed for proper cooling.

Comment: Depends on the cost, the changce to repair it (esp without them completedly replacing the motherboard which mightr be expensive), possible warrenty etc. And I guess if you need one repaired laptop, so effort might be best spent on one of them.

I am more worried abnout the "every time i plug in something, the sparks go out. ". No sense in getting it repaired it the root cause likely kills it again soon afterward.

Comment: First laptop is almost 5 years old, 980M is very old graphics card, but the second one is released before few months and still has warrany. I am still waiting to get info from authorized service for second laptop.

Comment: A what can I do with that "sparks"?

Comment: Having bad power delivery is obviously not great, but one would expect your charger to fry rather than your laptop. If your circuit brakers flip all the time, you are either stressing the system too much or there is a problem hiding somewhere. You should definitely get that looked at, its not normal and can be a fire hazard. As for both laptops showing the same error, i think its just bad luck. Get the second one fixed under warranty. Wether or not its worth having the older one fixed is upto you.

Comment: "The thing with power is that every time i plug in something, the sparks go out. "suggests problem with the electric supply to the house/room. Please get that checked by a qualified electrician.